# Download a CSV file in EmberJs

Tags: javascript, ajax, csv, ember.js

I have tried a myriad of different function calls, but can't seem to figure out how to trigger a download for a CSV in EmberJs.

Here is my latest code:

```
let endpoint = '/api/foo/';
let options = {
    url: endpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'text'
};
return new Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  options.success = function(result) {
      var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result);
      window.open(uri, 'foo.csv');
  };
  options.error = (xhr, errorThrown) => {
    console.log('error');
    // return Ember.run(null, reject, this.didError(xhr, xhr.status, xhr.responseJSON, 1));
  };
  Ember.$.ajax(options);
});
```

This code doesn't raise any server or client side errors. It's getting a 200 response. No javascript errors, and doesn't console log anything, so I know it's not hitting the error block. But... it won't trigger the file download on the client.  Does anyone know what is missing?

Comment: is there something special to your request or is it just a simple url call ? I´m using an action {{action "downloadOrdersCSV"}} to call downloadOrdersCSV:function(){window.open("yoururl",'_blank');}

Answer (score 0):

I am unable to test this, but I believe your issue is with returning a `new` promise, whereas what you really want is to return the promise itself.

So change your code to:

```
let endpoint = '/api/foo/';
let options = {
    url: endpoint,
    type: 'POST',
    data: {},
    dataType: 'text'
};
return Ember.RSVP.Promise((resolve, reject) => {  // note the deletion of new
  options.success = function(result) {
      var uri = 'data:application/csv;charset=UTF-8,' + encodeURIComponent(result);
      window.open(uri, 'foo.csv');
  };
  options.error = (xhr, errorThrown) => {
    console.log('error');
    // return Ember.run(null, reject, this.didError(xhr, xhr.status, xhr.responseJSON, 1));
  };
  Ember.$.ajax(options);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

In implementing a similar piece of functionality, I went for a different route. Rather than creating an AJAX request, I create a form and submit it to the server. My API endpoint will then return the CSV in the response, with the appropriate Content-Disposition headers, and the browser will just download the file.

(Depending on your authentication scheme, you may have to include your authentication token as a value in your form data).

Example code below. You'll see I'm adding the auth token. The form's action URL is set in the markup of the page, but you could set it dynamically here if you wanted.

```
csvDownload () {
    let form = Ember.$('#csvdownloadform')
    let input = Ember.$('#csvdownloadtoken')
    input.val(this.get('session').get('session.content.authenticated.token'))
    form.submit()
    input.val('')
    form_func.val('')
},
```